# Android ListView displaying one item per page

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview  that uses an adapter who receives a string array as an argument. When I look at the listview it displays 1 item then it shows a lot of blank space behind it that is followed by the next item if I scroll down. What could be the problem?

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] camere) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, camere);
}
boolean parola = true;
boolean intra = true;
String player_id, room_id;
String siteul = "some_site";
String site;
HashMap<String, String> hash;

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView camera;
    TextView players;
    TextView max_players;
    ImageView privata;
    Button Buton;
    String room_id, nume;
}
ViewHolder ceva;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    String variabile[] = getItem(position).split("\\s+");

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater linflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.camera = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Nume);
        holder.players = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.players);
        holder.max_players = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.max_players);
        holder.privata = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.privata);
        holder.Buton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Buton);
        holder.camera.setText(variabile[0]);
        if (!variabile[1].equals("true")) {
            parola = false;
            holder.privata.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        holder.players.setText(variabile[2]);
        holder.max_players.setText(variabile[3]);
        holder.room_id = variabile[4];
        holder.nume = variabile[5];

        holder.Buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int playeri = Integer.parseInt(holder.players.getText().toString());
                int maximi = Integer.parseInt(holder.max_players.getText().toString());
                if(playeri < maximi)
                {
                    hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hash.put("name", holder.nume);
                    hash.put("room", holder.room_id);
                    if (intra) {
                        holder.Buton.setText("Iesi");
                        site = siteul + "/join";
                        intra = false;
                    } else {
                        holder.Buton.setText("Intra");
                        site = siteul + "/leave";
                        intra = true;
                    }
                    new ATask((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).execute(site);
                }
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.Buton.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    return convertView;
}

public void CheckStart()
{
    site = siteul + "/checkstart";
    hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hash.put("room", room_id);
    new ATask(ceva).execute(site);
}

public void CheckPlayers()
{
    site = siteul + "/checkplayers";
    hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hash.put("room", room_id);
    new ATask(ceva).execute(site);
}

public void openGame(String litera)
{
    Intent incercare = new Intent(getContext(), Game.class);
    incercare.putExtra("nume", player_id);
    incercare.putExtra("room", room_id);
    incercare.putExtra("litera", litera);
    incercare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getContext().startActivity(incercare);
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}

public class ATask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String rez = "";
    ViewHolder myHolder;
    public ATask(ViewHolder view) {
        myHolder = view;
        ceva = myHolder;
        room_id = myHolder.room_id;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //try {
        try {
            Log.e("rasp", site);
            URL obj = new URL(site);
            try {
                Log.e("rasp", obj.toString());
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                // For POST only - START
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                os.write(getPostDataString(hash).getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                // For POST only - END
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                Log.e("rasp", "response code-ul e " + Integer.toString(responseCode));
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    // print result
                    rez = response.toString();
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("rasp", "POST request not worked");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("naspa", "E corupt!");
        }
        //} catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.e("rasp", "aia e");
        //}
        return rez;
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (rez.charAt(0) == 'Y')
            openGame(rez.substring(2));
        else if (rez.charAt(0) == 'V' && !intra)
        {
            TextView players_mare = myHolder.players;
            players_mare.setText(rez.substring(2));
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do something after 1s = 1000ms
                    CheckStart();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        else if(rez.charAt(0) == 'G')
            CheckPlayers();
        else if(rez.charAt(0) == 'Z')
        {
            TextView players_mare = myHolder.players;
            players_mare.setText(rez.substring(2));
        }
        else if (rez.charAt(0) == 'D')
        {
            player_id = rez.substring(2);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do something after 1s = 1000ms
                    CheckStart();
                }
            }, 400);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the xml of "custom_row.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_joc">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Nume camera"
            android:id="@+id/Nume"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Runde:"
            android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView15" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/runde"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buton_lock"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/privata" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/players"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?    android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="/"
            android:id="@+id/nu_trebuia_sa_aiba_id"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/max_players"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Intra"
            android:id="@+id/Buton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/e_sa_pacaleasca_match_parentu_de_la_linear_layout"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Add the xml for `R.layout.custom_row`

Answer (score 0):

From the `R.layout.custom_row` we can see that you make the root view(`RelativeLayout`) fill parent and make the height of `ScrollView` `match_parent`. So the `Scrollview` occupy the full screen. The blank space belongs to `scrollview`. I think you can remove the `scrollview` and make the root view(`RelativeLayout`) wrap content.

Try codes below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_joc">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Nume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Nume camera"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
                android:text="Runde:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/runde"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/privata"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buton_lock"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/players"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nu_trebuia_sa_aiba_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="/"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/max_players"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Buton"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Intra"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/e_sa_pacaleasca_match_parentu_de_la_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need the scrollview in case I have too many items to display on one page.

Comment: @Vali79 The `ListView` can also scroll when your item views occupy more than one page. I suggest don't use `ScrollView` in this demo cause if you use `ListView` and `ScrollView` simultaneously, you have to handle the sliding conflicts.

Comment: Deleted the scrollview, but it still looks the same.

Comment: I actually was able to make it work by deleting both the relative layout and the scrollview, leaving only the linear one. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your `custom_row.xml` :

change the `layout_height` of the `RelativeLayout`, `ScrollView` and the `LinearLayout` from `fill_parent` to `wrap_content`.